# Displaying top-selling product pairs

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem, I've spent a lot of time on. I have to display the pairs of items (Item1, Item2, How many) that appear on the invoices - and how many pairs have repeated. The table that connects invoices to goods is called "Transactions".
I Have 3 tables:

**Items:** IdItem, Name 
**Transactions:** IdTransaction, IdInvoice, IdItem
**Invoices:** IdInvoice

Result of SQL Query must be:

Item1 | Item2 | Number

Comment: Can you share with us a sample of your data ?

Comment: Please also help us understand what "pairs of items" means.  How are items paired, or what is your definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a self-join and aggregation:

```
select t1.IdItem as IdItem1, t2.IdItem as IdItem2, count(*)
from transactions t1 join
     transactions t2
     on t1.IdInvoice = t2.IdInvoice and
        t1.IdItem < t2.IdItem
group by t1.IdItem, t2.IdItem
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: It's working, this is what I ment, Thank You ! :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Items (
   IDItem INT,
   Name VARCHAR,
   PRIMARY KEY(IDItem)
);

CREATE TABLE Invoices (
   IDInvoice INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(IDInvoice)
);
CREATE TABLE Transactions (
   IDTransaction INT,
   IDInvoice INT,
   IDItem INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(IDTransaction),
   FOREIGN KEY (IDItem) REFERENCES Items(IDItem),
   FOREIGN KEY (IDInvoices) REFERENCES Invoices(IDInvoices)
)
```

If this is true then you need to query the results like this:

```
SELECT i.Name,in.IDInvoice FROM Transactions t
JOIN Items i ON i.IDItem = t.IDItem
JOIN Invoices in ON in.IDInvoice = t.IDInvoice
WHERE i.Name = item1
```